# Twitter V2 API 429 HTTP error not being caught

Tags: python, twitterapi-python

### Background and Code

I have the below function to handle rate limiting in Twitter's V2 API based on the [HTTP status codes](https://developer.twitter.com/ja/docs/basics/response-codes).

```py
from datetime import datetime
from osometweet.utils import pause_until

def manage_rate_limits(response):
    """Manage Twitter V2 Rate Limits
    This method takes in a `requests` response object after querying
    Twitter and uses the headers["x-rate-limit-remaining"] and
    headers["x-rate-limit-reset"] headers objects to manage Twitter's
    most common, time-dependent HTTP errors.
    Wiki Reference: https://github.com/osome-iu/osometweet/wiki/Info:-HTTP-Status-Codes-and-Errors
    Twitter Reference: https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting
    """
    while True:

        # The x-rate-limit-remaining parameter is not always present.
        #    If it is, we want to use it.
        try:
            # Get number of requests left with our tokens
            remaining_requests = int(response.headers["x-rate-limit-remaining"])

            # If that number is one, we get the reset-time
            #   and wait until then, plus 15 seconds (your welcome Twitter).
            # The regular 429 exception is caught below as well,
            #   however, we want to program defensively, where possible.
            if remaining_requests == 1:
                buffer_wait_time = 15
                resume_time = datetime.fromtimestamp( int(response.headers["x-rate-limit-reset"]) + buffer_wait_time )
                print(f"One request from being rate limited. Waiting on Twitter.\n\tResume Time: {resume_time}")
                pause_until(resume_time)
        
        except Exception as e:
            print("An x-rate-limit-* parameter is likely missing...")
            print(e)

        # Explicitly checking for time dependent errors.
        # Most of these errors can be solved simply by waiting
        # a little while and pinging Twitter again - so that's what we do.
        if response.status_code != 200:

            # Too many requests error
            if response.status_code == 429:
                buffer_wait_time = 15
                resume_time = datetime.fromtimestamp( int(response.headers["x-rate-limit-reset"]) + buffer_wait_time )
                print(f"Too many requests. Waiting on Twitter.\n\tResume Time: {resume_time}")
                pause_until(resume_time)

            # Twitter internal server error
            elif response.status_code == 500:
                # Twitter needs a break, so we wait 30 seconds
                resume_time = datetime.now().timestamp() + 30
                print(f"Internal server error @ Twitter. Giving Twitter a break...\n\tResume Time: {resume_time}")
                pause_until(resume_time)

            # Twitter service unavailable error
            elif response.status_code == 503:
                # Twitter needs a break, so we wait 30 seconds
                resume_time = datetime.now().timestamp() + 30
                print(f"Twitter service unavailable. Giving Twitter a break...\n\tResume Time: {resume_time}")
                pause_until(resume_time)

            # If we get this far, we've done something wrong and should exit
            raise Exception(
                "Request returned an error: {} {}".format(
                    response.status_code, response.text
                )
            )

        # Each time we get a 200 response, exit the function and return the response object
        if response.ok:
            return response
```

This function is fed a response object from a `requests` call like the below

```py
response = requests.get(
            url,
            headers=self._header,
            params=payload
            )

response = manage_rate_limits(response)
```

In the above response call the parameters are the following:

where

- `url` = Twitter's base endpoint URL (in this case it is the full archive academic search)
- `params`/`payload` = a combination of endpoint search operators (these should be irrelevant but I can include if necessary)
- `headers`/`self._bearer_token` is a user `bearer_token` in the below proper header form

```py
self._header = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {MY_BEARER_TOKEN}"}
```

#### Question & Error:

Using the above code, I get a long-running script that returns the below error from the `rate_limit_manager` function.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scratch/mdeverna/Superspreaders/src/get_rts_of_user.py", line 218, in get_rts_of_user
    full_archive_search = True
  File "/nfs/nfs5/home/scratch/mdeverna/osometweet/osometweet/api.py", line 248, in search
    response = self._oauth.make_request(url, payload)
  File "/nfs/nfs5/home/scratch/mdeverna/osometweet/osometweet/oauth.py", line 181, in make_request
    response = manage_rate_limits(response)
  File "/nfs/nfs5/home/scratch/mdeverna/osometweet/osometweet/rate_limit_manager.py", line 67, in manage_rate_limits
    response.status_code, response.text
Exception: Request returned an error: 429 {"title":"Too Many Requests","type":"about:blank","status":429,"detail":"Too Many Requests"}
```

What I don't understand is that the line that prints this exception is...

```
# If we get this far, we've done something wrong and should exit
raise Exception(
    "Request returned an error: {} {}".format(
        response.status_code, response.text
         )
```

... and this illustrates the `response.status_code` prints (equals) `429`, however, the conditional earlier in this function *checks for exactly this status code but seems to miss it*. It seems like the condition which checks if the status code = 429 is being skipped, only to print down below that the status code is 429?

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the status code is 429 or 500 or 503, you're going to flow off the bottom of the if/elif/elif sequence and right into the `raise`.  Did you intend to `return` at the end of each?  Or did you mean for the `raise` to be in an `else:` clause?

Comment: oh, wow. I see now ::facepalm::  - yes, the `raise` line should be within an `else:` clause. So it seems like my code is probably working fine it's just going to throw an error no matter what after properly handling the error...